# "mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found" is being produced when entering book code

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Output:

```
Welcome back  Manas . What do you want to do? 

1.Add book to borrow
2.Return book borrowed
3.Check existing borrowed book(s)
4.Logout
Enter your choice: 1
Enter code of book to be borrowedAA111
```

Results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\Desktop\test.txt", line 53, in 
> userlist(username,bookcode,bookborrowdate)   File "C:\Users\Rotten\Desktop\test.txt", line 22, in userlist
> cursor.execute("insert into userlist values(%s,%s);",(username,bookdict,))   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py",
> line 243, in execute
> self._cnx.handle_unread_result()   File "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
> line 794, in handle_unread_result
> raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found") mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Here is the minimal code sample

```
import mysql.connector
import hashlib
import os
from datetime import date
mycon=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="123456",database="library",charset="utf8mb4")
cursor=mycon.cursor()
stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users'"
cursor.execute(stmt)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result:
    pass
else:
    cursor.execute("create table userlist(username varchar(20),book varchar(200));")
def userlist(username,bookcode,bookborrowdate):
    bookdict={}
    booktick=cursor.execute("Select book from userlist where username=%s",(username,))
    if booktick is not None:
        bookdict=booktick
    else:
        pass
    bookdict.update({'bookcode':'bookborrowdate'})
    cursor.execute("insert into userlist values(%s,%s);",(username,bookdict,))
    mycon.commit()
def userfull(username):
    cursor.execute("select book from userlist where username=%s;",(username,))
    bookdata=cursor.fetchone()
    if bookdata is None:
        print("No books")
    else:
        bookneed=bookdata[0]
        for key, value in bookneed.items():
            print(key, ' : ', value)
def userret(username,bookcode):
    cursor.execute("select book from userlist where username=%s;",(username,))
    bookreturn=cursor.fetchone()
    if bookreturn is None:
        print("No books borrowed")
    else:
        bookretex=bookreturn[0]
        if bookcode in bookretex:
            del bookretex[bookcode]
username="Manas"
print("Welcome back ",username,". What do you want to do? \n")
print("1.Add book to borrow")
print("2.Return book borrowed")
print("3.Check existing borrowed book(s)")
print("4.Logout")
usch=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
if usch==1:
    while True:
        bookcode=input("Enter code of book to be borrowed")
        bookborrowdate=date.today()
        userlist(username,bookcode,bookborrowdate)
        td=timedelta(10)
        print("Please return this book by",bookborrowdate+td)
        choice=input("Continue?[y/n]")
        if choice in 'Yy':
            continue
        else:
            break
elif usch==2:
    while True:
        bookcode=input("Enter code of borrowed book to be returned")
        returnticket=userret(username,bookcode)
        returncookie=input("continue? [y/n]: ")
        if returncookie in "Yy":
            continue
        else:
            break
elif usch==3:
    userfull()
elif usch==4:
    print("Logging out of ",username,"...")
    username=None
else:
    print("Wrong input, try again")
```

Comment: my ide doesn't know what timedelta is, so it throws an error. your ide should show such errors and allow debugging line for line, what are you using

Comment: also (username,bookdict,))  is not correct, the last comma is only needed if you oass only one parameter with two it gives an error.

Comment: In this case, the most likely cause of `Unread result found` is that you query returns more than one record, but you are only reading one (with `fetchone()`).  You need to read all the fetched rows (for example by looping over `cursor.fetchall()`), or improve your query so that it only returns a single record.

Comment: @nbk im using IDLE, VSC broke for some reason

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm confused by what you mean by "looping over cursor.fetchall())" Im quite new, so I only know rudimentary things..

Comment: fix the errors  mentioned maybe we find the problem where you have multiple rows that i can't see at the moment

Comment: @nbk It is an empty set, so it should not contain anything

Comment: have you fixed the error i mentioned at the begining?

Comment: time delta, i imported it using ```from datetime import date,timedelta``` and the commas, i removed the extras. However, I still do not understand what snakecharmerb suggested me to do. @nbk

Comment: `cursor.fetchall()` will return a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), and it's common to use [for loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to act on each element of a list.  I'd recommend reading through the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to learn more about the basics of Python.

Comment: However in this particular case it seems the problem is the first query in the `userlist` function: you do not fetch the result of this query, and this causes an error when the code tries to do an insert later in the function.

Comment: Isnt that what the booktick is doing? storing the result?

Comment: @snakecharmerb sorry, forgot to ping

Comment: The dictionary seems to be working fine. Is there any way to "empty" a cursor?

Comment: ok iwrote a date before the function and then  the problem was gone. still i don't under stand your function you get all books with that username, but you never fetch any book, so `bookdict=booktick` should give you an error

Comment: @snakecharmerb setting buffered=True  into mysql.connector.connect seems to have fixed the unread problem, however, i still cannot add a dict into the table

Comment: @nbk Yes, but the thing is, the table userlist is an empty set, so it should not have run that if statement, or is that a mistake on my part again?

Comment: that doesn't matter you have to fetch the rows of course an empty result is still a result that has to be fetched, this was already metioned

Comment: I see now, how do I fix these kinds of errors?

Comment: thes ame way as before, fetch all data available before going on, you could at that pointbhavbe 10 books or none all possibilities have to be tested

Comment: running a fetchall() before this returns an empty list []

Comment: and it fixed itself, and instead having a nonetype no update attribute error after I tried using bookdict.update